# Android ClassNotFoundException for Support v7 TestActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-support-library

I have an app that I just received a crash report for. I don't have the full stack trace with me right now, but it was from `ActivityLoader.performLaunchActivity`.

The class it is trying to launch is `android.support.v7.widget.TestActivity`. I certainly never try to load this activity anywhere in my app.

The device is a Samsung Galaxy Nexus running 4.1.1 rooted. The stacktrace looked normal to me (no xposed or anything like that).

Anyone ever see anything like this?

**EDIT:** Here's the stacktrace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.cpsolutions.contacts/android.support.v7.widget.TestActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.TestActivity
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1998)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:119)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4873)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:528)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.TestActivity
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:72)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:524)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader._logged_loadClass(ClassLoader.java:484)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:476)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1989)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:119)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4873)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:528)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Without full log trace,seems not possible

Comment: are you using `RecyclerView` or `CardView`?

Comment: @Ishrat see the question update

Comment: @royB I am, but I've never seen them try to load an `Activity`

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Nexus running 4.1.1 rooted. on which ROM?

Comment: @Ishrat I have no idea. Just what the crash reporter (Crashlytics) tells me

Comment: Device is running on Custom ROM, and somehow customizer delete that class or package from the OS, and your application trying to access that activity, then no worry about this, this happens rarely.

Comment: @Ishrat the problem is nothing should be launching that `Activity`. I never try to access it, and given its name, it seems like nothing should be trying to access it.

Comment: Please Show your launcher activity code of OnCreate method,

Comment: @Ishrat there is no launcher activity; it is a widget. In any case, I assure you that there is nothing in my code launching `android.support.v7.widget.TestActivity`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72898/discussion-between-ishrat-and-eliezer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After posting this in the [Android issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159846), I've gotten a response saying that it was an issue with Gradle that has been resolved, and will be reflected in the support libraries when they're updated.

Answer (score 1):

This morning I have received from my BugTracker system the same exception in few seconds for several devices

- Google Nexus 5 with Android 4.4.2
- Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.1.1

Looks like someone have extracted the APK and installed in some simulator (I suspect this also because the reported screen size is 480x800 that is not a screen size of nexus 5.

So I think that this is not a real exception (or at least an exception thrown by our application) but some test made by someone.

The exception received is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{it.frusso.mdpalette/android.support.v7.widget.TestActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.TestActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/it.frusso.mdpalette-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/it.frusso.mdpalette-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:122)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5122)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.TestActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/it.frusso.mdpalette-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/it.frusso.mdpalette-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader._logged_loadClass(ClassLoader.java:480)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:472)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2126)
    ... 11 more
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.TestActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/it.frusso.mdpalette-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/it.frusso.mdpalette-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader._logged_loadClass(ClassLoader.java:480)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:472)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:122)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5122)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have also received a android.view.WindowManager.BadTokenException